# escape JavaScript dot in kendo ui grid column field

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We are using kendo ui grid with angularjs successfully so far, but every now and then back end server responds with dot (.) in field for grid column definition.

When that happens, kendo grid looks for object structure in the grid data response.

For example:
When column field has 'person.firstname', kendo grid looks for person: {firstname: 'blah'} in data, where server responds with "person.firstname":" blah" in data json.

How can I escape this dot in column field definition and grid data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotes on the model:

```
model: {
    fields: {"person.firstname": {"type":"string"} }
      }
```

and bracket notation:

```
columns: [{
          field:["person.firstname"]
         }]
```